# Reading serial port input

Tags: python, python-2.7, psychopy

I have a button box connected via a serial port adapter to a USB port.

The button box has 5 buttons. What I am trying to do, is to record what button has been pressed (and when). So far, I will focus on what button. The code will be used in a PsychoPy experiment.

What I am doing so far is this:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as port_list
ports = list(port_list.comports()) # search for the devices
#for p in ports: print (p)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200, timeout=1)


if(ser.isOpen() == False): #open the serial port only if NOT open yet
    ser.open()

ser.flushInput() #erase all info in the box about previous button-presses

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

line = ser.read()
print(chr(line))
ser.close()
```

If I do this, however, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

If I check `line` after the button press, I get the following value:

```
'\x02'
```

The value changes according to the button pressed: `'\x02'`, `'\x03'` etc. So it seems to at least detect the right button pressed.

The last thing I tried to do is the following. In order to convert the string into an integer, I tried to replace `'\x0'`:

```
line
a=str(line)
a.replace('\x0', "")
a
```

And I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\x02'` is escaped code for a string containing ONE character with (ascii/ansi/unicode) value 2. Your line variable is 1 character long. Try `len(line)`

If you want to print the button number by extracting the value of this character try: `print(ord(line[0]))`